# How do i hide a row in grid when clicked on image button which is in that row?

Tags: .net, gridview, datagridview

I am Having Grid with few columns in which one column is a Image. When clicked on that image i want that row to be Hide.

[image]

Here when i click on the last column my row must be hidden,

How can i make it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> These few steps will help you.

1. Make sure the image column that you are clicking is an ImgaeButton
2. The Imgaebutton will have a CommandName and CommandArguement property
3. Use the RowCommand event of the gridview which will do the trick for you.

> Something like this.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton runat="server" id="gvibtn"
                             CommandName="HideRow" 
                             CommandArgument='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>'
                             Text='<%# Bind("Text") %>'>       
            </asp:ImageButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

> Code behind will look something like this.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName == "HideRow")
    {
        int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        // now you got the rowindex, run your hiding logic here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write an event handler for the image cell's click event.  The sender of that event will be the image cell.  You can take the sender and cast it back to a cell, and then get the Parent of that cell (which will be the row) and set the Visible property to false for the parent row.